# Updating table based on the interval from another. SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count how many men was working each hour. I have two tables:

```
Hour     Men
------------
6        0
7        0
8        0
9        0
10       0
11       0
12       0
```

where `"Men"` column is the count of men. Another table is:

```
ClockedInHour     ClockedOutHour
6                 10
7                 10
8                 12
6                 11
9                 12
```

So for every entry in the second table, I need to increment `"Men"` column in the first table for every hour between `"ClockedInHour"` and `"ClockedOutHour"` including those in the table, and, if possible, to do it without cursor.

Additional condition: it will be a part of the table-valued function.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

```
DECLARE @Hour6 INT
SET @Hour6 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table2 where ClockedOutHour >= 6 and ClockedInHour <= 6)
DECLARE @Hour7 INT
SET @Hour7 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table2 where ClockedOutHour >= 7 and ClockedInHour <= 7)
DECLARE @Hour8 INT
SET @Hour8 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table2 where ClockedOutHour >= 8 and ClockedInHour <= 8)
DECLARE @Hour9 INT
SET @Hour9 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table2 where ClockedOutHour >= 9 and ClockedInHour <= 9)
DECLARE @Hour10 INT
SET @Hour10 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table2 where ClockedOutHour >= 10 and ClockedInHour <= 10)
DECLARE @Hour11 INT
SET @Hour11 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table2 where ClockedOutHour >= 11 and ClockedInHour <= 11)
DECLARE @Hour12 INT
SET @Hour12 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tc where ClockedOutHour >= 12 and ClockedInHour <= 12)

UPDATE @table1 SET Man = @Hour6 WHERE Hour = 6
UPDATE @table1 SET Man = @Hour7 WHERE Hour = 7
UPDATE @table1 SET Man = @Hour8 WHERE Hour = 8
UPDATE @table1 SET Man = @Hour9 WHERE Hour = 9
UPDATE @table1 SET Man = @Hour10 WHERE Hour = 10
UPDATE @table1 SET Man = @Hour11 WHERE Hour = 11
UPDATE @table1 SET Man = @Hour12 WHERE Hour = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a Insert Trigger as:

```
Go --terminate all preceding batch of statements

CREATE TRIGGER tg_MenCount ON dbo.table2 For INSERT
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON
--Ignore zero row updates, inserts
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN;

BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE T1
    set T1.men = T1.men +1
    FROM
       table1 T1
       INNER JOIN INSERTED I
       ON T1.hour between I.ClockedInHour and I.ClockedOutHour   
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF XACT_STATE() <> 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    --RAISERROR [rethrow caught error using @ErrorNumber, @ErrorMessage, etc]
END CATCH
GO
```

Comment: That should be a part of a table-valued function. Your code gives me an error: "'CREATE TRIGGER' must be the first statement in a query batch."

Comment: That's because you might be adding this definition in an ongoing batch. Terminate that batch with a Go statement.

Comment: In that case I don't have an access to the previously declared table variables which represent tables from the original post

Comment: You mean you have table1 and table2 as table variables or as defined objects in database?I would suggest to create staging tables

Comment: "@table1" and "@table2" as table variables